# User-friendly command to list all users on Ubuntu system?

Tags: command-line, users

Is there a user-friendly command I can use to list users in a console on an Ubuntu system?

When I `cat /etc/passwd` I get a hard-to-read list of users. It would be nice to see an alphabetized list, with entries arranged into columns, and with group names in parentheses beside the group IDs.

Comment: well, /etc/passwd *is* arranged into columns... if you want to see only a few colums, perhaps use `cut`. For alphabetized, there is `sort`. If you need the group names, play with join (which may actually be able to show only a subset of columns, btw).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Good way for nice output of /etc/passwd file:

```
$ column -nts: /etc/passwd
```

Now you can sort it:

```
$ column -nts: /etc/passwd | sort
```

With groups names in last column (no parenthesis):

```
$ paste -d: /etc/passwd <(groups $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd) | sed 's/.*: //') | column -nts: | sort
```

Comment: Thanks, these commands do what I want. To a newbie this is very daunting though... I suppose I'll have to learn how to create an alias for them.

Comment: On Centos column didn't like the `n` option.  `column -ts: /etc/passwd` worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

If you have root access on the machine, you can do the following:

```
sudo grep -vE '^[^*!]+:[*!]:' /etc/shadow | sort | cut -d: -f1 | while read user; do id $user; done | column -ts' ,' | vi '+set nowrap' -
```

## How it works

Become root to read the shadow file. You only require root privileges if you want to check if the user has a password set (human user), otherwise you can just `cat /etc/passwd` instead of `sudo grep ...`:

```
sudo
```

Only show users which have a password set:

```
grep -vE '^[^*!]+:[*!]:' /etc/shadow
```

Sort by username:

```
sort
```

Discard all information except for the username:

```
cut -d: -f1
```

Iterate through the usernames and enrich it with group infomration:

```
while read user; do id $user; done
```

Format the input into columns:

```
column -ts' ,'
```

Use vi to view the result:

```
vi '+set nowrap' -
```

---

## If you don't have root access,

try something like this:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | sort | while read user; do id $user; done | sed 's/\(\()\|^\)[^(]*(\|)\)/ /g' | column -t
```

Its output is a bit different, but I leave it as an exercise to the reader to combine the two parts in this answer into something that fully fits the job. (Don't you just love `sed`?)

Comment: "I leave it as an exercise to the reader..." :)

Answer (score 2):

Something that I do and it works for my purposes is

```
ls /home
```

Granted, that doesn't really give you a list of users rather a list of user's home directories and past user's directories but any command you want to do on a user that doesn't exist terminal will tell you and could be a hint to remove the home file that doesn't have a user or move it!

Comment: I like this. It gets the job done on a basic level.

Comment: This is the only truly user-friendly answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu it can be as follows:

seven fields from /etc/passwd stored in $f1,f2...,$f7

```
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do
 echo "User $f1 use $f7 shell and stores files in $f6 directory."
done < /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be easy with `join`, but `join` requires the files to be sorted **on the join field**. So it required (?) a workaround with temporary files. The output is sorted on user, and displays user, group, and group ID.

```
uag () {
  TEMP_GROUPS=/var/tmp/sorted_groups
  TEMP_USERS=/var/tmp/sorted_users
  cat /etc/group  | tr ":" " " | sort -k 3 -o $TEMP_GROUPS
  cat /etc/passwd | tr ":" " " | sort -k 4 -o $TEMP_USERS
  join -1 4 -2 3 -o 1.1,2.1,2.3 $TEMP_USERS $TEMP_GROUPS | sort
  rm $TEMP_GROUPS $TEMP_USERS
}
```

Translate a character into another with `tr`; `sort` according to a key field with `-k`, output to file with `-o`; join with regard to fields in the first (`-1`) and second (`-2`) file, output certain fields in the first file (`-o 1.1`) as well as the second (`,2.1,2.3`).

Comment: note that `/tmp` would be better, because FHS states that `/var/tmp` won't be wiped on reboots, which we don't really need.