# How can I use sed to print out unique users

Tags: bash, sed

I wish to print out the unique users in the system using only `sed`, using:

```
ls -la | sed '/^$USER$/p'
```

.... It gives me all files, matching to the current user, and prints out the lines they are in. Meaning it prints out all lines with all users.

Comment: You'd have to first sort user names and `sed` is inappropriate for sorting. A better option is to pipe through `sort -u`.

Comment: Which OS and version?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Bash shell

Comment: I did, add sort, but I need to find the unique user from ls -la using sed ...

Comment: Can you use plain ls ? You do understand that $USER is an environment variable set by login?

Comment: Where are you running the `ls` command from? What do you mean by "unique users"? That command will print all lines (you're missing `-n`).  Even if it did only print matching lines, that would only print lines containing the string `$USER` and not the current user (variables don't get expanded in single quotes). Please [edit] your question, show us i) the input you are parsing; ii) your desired output and, most importantly, iii) explain why in the world you would want to do this by parsing `ls` with `sed`. There are far better ways of getting a list of users on your system.

Comment: I don't quite understand, what you want to accomplish. Do you want to get all users, who own a file in the current folder? Why would you `grep` for the current one, then? Do you want to just get all users of the machine? Why would you want to use `ls` for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list all the users, that own a file in the current directory, you can use this command:

`ls -la | tr -s ' ' | cut -f3 -d ' ' | sort | uniq`

It lists all the files with `ls -la`, then collapses the multiple spaces into single ones with `tr -s ' '`, so we can use `cut -d ' ' -f3` to get the 3rd column of the output. `-d ' '` gives the delimiter and `-f3` the 3rd field.

Then we sort the list of users (the 3rd column) with `sort` and remove all neighbouring duplicate entries with `uniq`.

---

If you want to get a list of all users on your current system, you should take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63511/88357) answer by Nykakin.

Comment: `ls -la | awk '$3!=""{print $3}' | sort -u`

Comment: @Peter.O `sort -u`: Learned something. Thanks.